# Show root of unity and order

Tags: proof-writing, roots-of-unity

I have this math problem:

> Set $$z=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$$ Show that $z$ is a root of
>    unity, find its order, and express $z^{100}$ in the form $a+bi$.

I'm not 100% sure how to do this. This is what I dod so far. I changed $z$ to exponential form and got $z = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$. I know that $z^n=1$ for $z$ to be a root of unity... so doesn't $(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}})^0=1$? does that prove that it is a root of unity? Also, how would I find the order from this? Thanks

Comment: Any number (except 0) to the power of 0 is equal to 1.

Comment: Yeah, so does that answer the first question?

Comment: No, I can say that 50^0 = 1, but that doesn't mean 50 is a root of unity. z is a root of unity if z^n is equal to 1, but n cannot be 0.

Comment: The order of the root is the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have to exponentiate $z$ with to get 1. That answers your first two questions, the third is easy once you substitute $z^n=1$, since that provides cyclic exponentiation.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? Shouldn't it be $-\frac 12$ rather than $\frac 12$?

Answer (score 2):

You need a positive $n$ to be a root of unity and the minimum such $n$ is its order.   Remember that $1=e^{2k\pi i}$ for any integer $k$.  So,  what's the smallest positive $n$ that gets you to a multiple of $2\pi i?$

From there, every time you go that many times around you get back to 1, so you can reduce 100 mod the order to simplify your calculation

Comment: Ok, so I have that $n=6$. So would the order be 6?

Comment: Correct.  So every time you go around 6 times you hit 1,  so reduce 100 mod 6 to answer your second question

Answer (score 1):

more to the point $(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}})^{6n}=1$ for every integer $n$

so $z^{100}= z^{96} z^4=z^4=(e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$z=-j$, where $j$ is the cubic root of unity: $\;\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\mathrm i\pi}3}$. Whence …